# c# Monogame/XNA Keep textures stick together while moving fast

Tags: c#, object, xna, textures, monogame

Currently I try to write a 2D roulette wheel in C# using Monogame as framework.
I'm quiet experienced with Monogame but I never had to manage fast moving textures to stick together tho.

The idea is that 3 textures(black, red, green) are connected to each other in a line of 15 objects.
That's fine as long as I don't start to scroll all these objects to actually "make the wheel move".

After moving for a while, the textures are no more connected to each other. They get some space in between or start to overlap.
I made a short Video to clarify the problem: https://puu.sh/vwbyU/d396c6ad99.mp4 (It's about 10 MB, some Browsers may have download it before it shows up)

This is the most important code:

```
const int _roulleteOffset = 170; // X coordinate to start at
Sprite[] fieldList = new Sprite[15]; // Represents my wheel (Array of my roulette fields/textures)
Rectangle scrollArea; // Fixed Area for the complete fieldList
float scrollSpeed = 0.0f; // Scrollspeed of the wheel. 0 on start.

// First I call the Content.Load to fill fieldList.Texture then
// this is called to position the "wheel" objects
private void AdditionalInit()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldList.Length; i++)
    {
        fieldList[i].Position = new Vector2(_roulleteOffset + i * fieldList[i].Texture.Width, Statics.GAME_WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2 - fieldList[i].Texture.Height / 2); 
    }
    scrollArea = new Rectangle((int)fieldList[0].Position.X, (int)fieldList[0].Position.Y, fieldList[0].Texture.Height * fieldList.Length + 30, fieldList[0].Texture.Height);
}

// This Method is called in Update() - And I guess the problem has to be fixed here
private void ScrollRoulette()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldList.Length; i++)
    {
        fieldList[i].position.X += scrollSpeed; // scrollSpeed is set with pressing + or - on keyboard
        if (fieldList[i].Position.X >= scrollArea.Width + fieldList[i].Texture.Width)
        {
            // After leaving the "scrollArea" set it to the start of it (Leaving on right side and entering at the left side again)
            fieldList[i].position.X = scrollArea.X - fieldList[i].Texture.Width;
        }
    }
}

// The part of my Draw Method. But I don't think that I made a mistake here
public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldList.Length; i++)
    {
        Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Draw(fieldList[i].Texture, fieldList[i].Position, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
    Statics.SPRITEBATCH.End();
}
```

Just watch the Video to understand what I'm talking about. Maybe you can help me with it. Even on slow speed the textures starts to disconnect or overlap over time.

Comment: When you set the scrollSpeed to have a constant value (like 10) from the beginning and later stop it to 0 directly, does this effect still happen?

Comment: If not, I think the problem is that the difference between fieldList[i].Position.X and scrollArea.Width + fieldList[i].Texture.Width (in the condition in ScrollRoulette method) will vary for each field and adding this difference to the position when you set it on the next line might help.

Comment: This kinda helps to find a solution but is not the solution. If I set the speed to 10, it only creates one small gap like ~10pixel wide. But while scrolling with that constant value of 10, it looks fine. As soon as I lower or higher the speed it will create more gaps or overlap eventually again. https://puu.sh/vwlk2/9660fac300.jpg This is the gap, the rest looks fine after scrolling for about a minute. And it looks like that http://puu.sh/vwlmy/da777df27e.jpg after setting the speed down while it scrolls.

Comment: Adding the scrollspeed to the position as a second line in the condition also did like nothing https://puu.sh/vwluw/807b4ca99d.jpg Very strange behavior.

Comment: Just to make sure, can you try replacing the set position line with this? fieldList[i].position.X = scrollArea.X + scrollArea.Width - fieldList[i].Position.X;

Comment: That makes it worse :o http://puu.sh/vwpKo/c6463bf78f.mp4

Answer (score 0):

With help from another german forum I resolved the problem! Thanks god. Took me a whole day these 1 line. I just had to adjust the positioning of the incoming tile. Not just set pos.x to the start.

```
    private void ScrollRoulette()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldList.Length; i++)
        {
            fieldList[i].position.X += scrollSpeed;

            if (fieldList[i].Position.X >= scrollArea.Width + (fieldList[i].Texture.Width * 2))
            {
                // This works now
                fieldList[i].position.X = scrollArea.X + (fieldList[i].Position.X - (scrollArea.Width + scrollArea.X) );
            }                
        }
    }
```